# MySQL FIND_IN_SET function with special character not working

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, find-in-set, mariasql

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyDB.`tag_quicktrend`(
    IN taglist TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM taginfo
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tagname,taglist);
END;
```

When I call SP:
`call sp_chart_band_tag_quicktrend('YH05_한글')` it return correct tag.
`call sp_chart_band_tag_quicktrend('YH05_한글,~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`')`

but it return only YH05_한글 tag.

The value ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\=-` is a tagname in Database.

[image]

And this is data in database:

[image]

And version MySQL:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

**10.3.9-MariaDB**

Comment: I use mysql, i also tag mssql to help

Comment: It doesn't help - its a totally different technology

Comment: Please provide a working test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found problem because I set this mode.

```
SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES');
```

This equal (=) query return empty

```
select * from taginfo where tagname = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`'
```

When I remove the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES by `SET @@SQL_MODE = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

```
select * from taginfo where tagname = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`'
```

it returns row with tagname = ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./';[]\=-`

so that FIND_IN_SET function matches correct values

Comment: Why would you disable this setting? Why not replace all ` \ ` with ` \\ `?

Comment: yes, we can use \\ instead of set NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode